# ImageMagick using convert and rename output

Tags: linux, bash, imagemagick

I a directory I have several files name like 
13992.jpg
13993.jpg
13994.jpg
13995.jpg
...

How do I rename these files using convert?
I have tried

```sh
 convert -thumbnail 62 %d.jpg[11000-19000] $d_thumb.jpg
```

but it is not working...
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want to run convert in a loop, like

```
for pic in *.jpg; do
    echo convert "$options" "$pic" "${pic%.*}.thumb.jpg"
done
```

consider also this little "trick" for renaming:

```
pic=foo123     # file name stripped of extension
echo "convert options..." $pic{,.thumb}.jpg
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use :

```
convert -thumbnail 62 -set filename:f '%d/%t' %d.jpg[11000-19000] %[filename:f]_thumb.jpg
```

The trick is to use a custom attribute `filename:f` to store the input filename with path `%d/` and without extension `%t`. This attribute is used to create the output filename.

Ref:

https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#set
https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php

Comment: While this command may help answer this question, a code only answer is not high quality.  It would be better to explain what all the options do and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have

```
for IMG in 1[1-8]???.jpg 19000.jpg; do
    echo convert -thumbnail 62 "$IMG" "${IMG%.jpg}_thumb.jpg"
done
```

Remove `echo` if already correct.

Comment: please try. 1[1-9]???.jpg on for IMG line may not expand to list of matching files. there's also a double quote missing

Comment: Oh yes I missed the ending quote.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/foob: line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'   -  result of missing closing quotesd